# Deep nested resources rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I understand deep nested resource should not be adopted, however i do not know how to convert it properly to a 1 level nested resources. If clean tutorial exists show me the tutorial and I will learn it. If not Then please help with my problem. Here my route.rb

```
resources :article do
  resources :picture
  resources :comments do
    resources :repcomments
  end
end
resources :reports
```

I can do article, picture, comments but not to sure how to approach the third level of reports. The idea comes that an article can have comments and where the comment could be reported to management. Everythings plays in the article#show pages and here the controller

```
  def show
    @art = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @art.comments.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @art }
    end
  end
```

Here the view form in article#show

```
<%= @art.title %>
<%= @art.content %>
Comment
<%= form_for [@art, current_customer.comments.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %><br />
  <%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
<% end %>
# End of form comments
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.description %>
  <div>Report</div>
  <%= form_for [@art, comment, repcomments.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Report it" %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

I am getting a no define method and not to sure how to approach it. Thanks in advance

Here the route file

```
 article_comment_repcomments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments(.:format)          repcomments#index
                              POST   /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments(.:format)          repcomments#create
 new_article_comment_repcomment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments/new(.:format)      repcomments#new
edit_article_comment_repcomment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments/:id/edit(.:format) repcomments#edit
     article_comment_repcomment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments/:id(.:format)      repcomments#show
                              PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments/:id(.:format)      repcomments#update
                              DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:comment_id/repcomments/:id(.:format)      repcomments#destroy
```

Here the models

```
class Repcomments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :article
  attr_accessible :acknowledged, :body, :completed, :customer_id, :article_id
end
```

Here my controller repcomments

```
class RepcommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /repcomments
  # GET /repcomments.json
  def index
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomments = Repcomment.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @repcomments }
    end
  end

  # GET /repcomments/1
  # GET /repcomments/1.json
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomment = Repcomment.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @repcomment }
    end
  end

  # GET /repcomments/new
  # GET /repcomments/new.json
  def new
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomment = Repcomment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @repcomment }
    end
  end

  # GET /repcomments/1/edit
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomment = @comments.repcomments.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /repcomments
  # POST /repcomments.json
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomment = @comments.repcomments.build(params[:repcomment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @repcomment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @repcomment, notice: 'Repcomment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @repcomment, status: :created, location: @repcomment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @repcomment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /repcomments/1
  # PUT /repcomments/1.json
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomment = @comment.repcomments.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @repcomment.update_attributes(params[:repcomment])
        format.html { redirect_to @repcomment, notice: 'Repcomment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @repcomment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /repcomments/1
  # DELETE /repcomments/1.json
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @articles.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
    @repcomment = @comments.repcomments.find(params[:id])
    @repcomment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to repcomments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end


NameError in Article#show
Showing /home/jean/rail/voix/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #70 raised:
undefined local variable or method `repcomments' for #<#<Class:0xaf24860>:0xaafe934>
```

So pretty much is the referencing

Comment: Can you paste the output of running "rake routes" and verify that you are trying to access the correct url?

Comment: Mind pasting some of your Model names?

Comment: Well originally it was report_comments, then i figure that it maybe cause by the 2 name word so i just change it to repcomments. Ill update the content to current if you want.

Comment: Ca you be more precise about the error you get?

Comment: Added the error description i am having atm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looking at your code, I can see one problem in your routes: `:article` and `:picture` need to be plural.

```
resources :articles do
    resources :pictures
    resources :comments do
        resources :repcomments
    end
end
resources :reports
```

Also, you don't need to nest `:repcomments` within `:articles`. In addition to what you already have in your routes, you can add:

```
resources :comments do
    resources :repcomments #and remove the other "resources :repcomments"
end
```

---

Yes, you would have `resources :comments` defined twice, but that's fine.

If you never do anything with comments outside the article scope, then you can write your routes like that:

```
resources :comments, only: [] do
    resources :repcomments
end
```

This way Rails wont generate the default rest routes (no /comments, no /comments/:id etc)

Comment: So i would define twice repcomments? Rails would reconize the nested generate only one different route instead of 2 different system?

Comment: Sorry, no, you would have to remove the `resources :repcomments` you currently have.

Comment: Updated my answer to address that.

Comment: this is one of the better nested routes answers i have found to-date thanks!